# Python - Calculate word frequency in percentage

Tags: python-3.x, file, percentage

I have a text where I have calculated the number of words and the frequency of the words. Now I have to display the top 7 percentage-wise. I have no clue how to do that. I know how to calcuate percentage, part/whole, but not sure how to write the code. I have done the sorting value-wise below.

```
def word_frequency():
"""
Function for word frequency
"""
d = dict()

with open(TEXT, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        for w in words:
            if w in d:
                d[w] += 1
            else:
                d[w] = 1

    dict_list = sorted(d.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
    print(dict_list[0:7])
```

This gives me this list:

```
[('the', 12), ('to', 8), ('of', 6), ('and', 5), ('a', 4), ('in', 4), ('Phil', 3)]
```

But how to calculate and present them with percentage instead of the value?
The word count of the text is `199`.

Regards

EDIT: NEW REVISED CODE

```
def word_frequency():
"""
Function for word frequency
"""
d = dict()

with open(TEXT, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        for w in words:
            if w in d:
                d[w] += round(1/1.99, 1)
            else:
                d[w] = round(1/1.99, 1)

    dict_list = sorted(d.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
    print(dict_list[0:7])
```

Gives me this list:

```
[('the', 6.0), ('to', 4.0), ('of', 3.0), ('and', 2.5), ('a', 2.0), ('in', 2.0), ('Phil', 1.5)]
```

I have the percentage-ish now but is there a way to present it in a nicer fashion?
Like:

```
the 6%
to 4%
of 3%
and 2.5%
a 2%
in 2%
Phil 1.5%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you can use a `Counter` from `collections` to count frequencies of words.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter

def most_common(instances):
    """Returns a list of (instance, count) sorted in total order and then from most to least common"""
    return sorted(sorted(Counter(instances).items(), key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Utilizing that `most_common` function, you can do like you said *"calculate percentage, part/whole"*. Which you do by iterating through the word and it's frequency and divides it by the total amount of words.

```
# words = list of strings
frequencies = most_common(words)
percentages = [(instance, count / len(words)) for instance, count in frequencies]
```

*Depending on your use case, then `re.findall(r"\w+", text)` might not be the best approach to extracting words.*

To get the top 7 words, you can slice `percentages`, by doing `percentages[:7]`.

```
import re

text = "Alice opened the door and found that it led into a small passage, not much larger than a rat-hole: she knelt down and looked along the passage into the loveliest garden you ever saw."

words = re.findall(r"\w+", text)
frequencies = most_common(words)
percentages = [(instance, count / len(words)) for instance, count in frequencies]

for word, percentage in percentages[:7]:
    print("%s %.2f%%" % (word, percentage * 100))
```

Which outputs:

```
the 8.57%
a 5.71%
and 5.71%
into 5.71%
passage 5.71%
Alice 2.86%
along 2.86%
```

If you want the same word in different casings, to count as the same. Then you can normalize all the words prior to calling `most_common`.

```
import unicodedata

def normalize_caseless(text):
    return unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text.casefold())
```

Then:

```
words = ...
```

Becomes:

```
words = list(map(normalize_caseless, ...))
```

Then a string containing the same word in different casings like this:

```
text = "Hello Test test TEST test TeSt"
```

Results in:

```
test 83.33%
hello 16.67%
```

Instead of:

```
test 33.33%
Hello 16.67%
TEST 16.67%
TeSt 16.67%
Test 16.67%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate items in the dictionary

```
for k, v in dict_list.items():
    percent = str(v) + ' %'
    result = k + ' ' + percent
    print(result)
```